# Deploying Custom SQL Views with Django

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-orm

I've written some custom PostgreSQL views, which I've wrapped with Django's ORM using the  [managed=False meta flag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#django.db.models.Options.managed). What's the best way to deploy these views, so that running syncdb updates them in the database, and also that the views exist in the test database when I run unittests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With an [initial SQL file](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/howto/initial-data/#providing-initial-sql-data).

Comment: Link throws a 404. That's why just-a-link answers just don't work